# Find $p$ such that $f$ defined by $f(x)=(|x|^\frac{d}{2}+|x|^d)^{-1}$ is in $L^p(R^d)$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, weak-convergence

The function f is definited in $\Bbb R^d$ by $$f(x)=\frac{1}{(|x|^\frac{d}{2}+|x|^d)}$$

How do you find $p\in[0.+\infty]$ such that $f(x)\in L^p$ ?

Any help is appreciated.

My attempt:

$r=|x| $, $r\in \Bbb R_+^d$:

$$||f||_p^p=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{dr}{r^\frac{dp}{2}(1+ r^\frac{d}{2})^p}$$

In the neighbourhood of $x=0$: $\frac{dp}{2}<1$

In the neighbourhood of $x=+\infty$ : $p>1$.

Comment: Since you took care of the problem mentioned in the previous comment by modifying the question, here is something else to chew on: to use the change of variable transforming an integral on $x$ to an integral on $r=|x|$, one does not simply replace $dx$ by $dr$.

Comment: Maybe, $$\int_{\mathbb R^d}(1+|x|^2)^{-s/2}\ dx<\infty\Leftrightarrow s>n/2$$ will be useful.

Comment: Apart from the volume of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$,  $\|f\|_p^p$ just depends on $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(x+\sqrt{x})^p}$$ that is convergent for $1<p<2$.

Comment: A further comment, the change of variable you did $x\longmapsto |x|$ can't be done, this map is not even bijective. For changing the variable $x$ in the integral to some other  $y=y(x)$ the map $x\longmapsto y$ must be (at least) a diffeomorphism of class $C^1$.

Comment: The formula for $\|f\|_p$ is wrong. The Jacobian of the change $x=r$, $r^{d´1}$ is missing.